# How would I show an HTML page in Eclipse at Design Time?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

When I'm writing crappy code in eclipse and I'm looking at a website for help I am constantly flipping back and forth between the browser and eclipse. To help me write crappy code faster is there a way to have a View that has a web page in it? I need to be able to set the URL and if I'm navigating around the site have a button to have it return to the original URL. So a URL Address box and 1 favorite link.

BTW I'm not a Eclipse plugin developer.

Comment: I am using Eclipse Kepler Java EE version. In this case, html file in project > right click > open with > web broswer. Done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. menu: window / show view / other ...
2. enter browser in the search box on top
3. select internal web browser

i would recommend you to install the web development tools

1. menu: help / install new software
2. select the software site for your eclipse installation (in my case it's "Helios - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios")
3. enter "web" in the search bar (and wait a little bit) and select "Eclipse Web Developer Toos" and "Web Page Edtior (Optional)"

Answer (score 2):

Just open your HTML file with web page editor. This will open in view where you can view the html code as well as the design it is going to create at run time.

Answer (score 1):

Looking for a button to close split design view (slow) in Eclipse "Web Page Editor", couldn't find it, until I noticed it was not default Generic Text Editor. Just close the tab window, find the html file in Navigator or Project Explorer, right click and select Open With > HTML Editor or another.

Answer (score 0):

The ticked answer did not work for me.

However, removing the line:

```
-javaagent:C:\Users\EdHeal\eclipse\java-2022-12\eclipse\lombok.jar
```

From `eclipse.ini` worked